# Retain 'plain' permalinks for Wordpress from import DB

Tags: php, wordpress, import, friendly-url, legacy-database

I'm in the process of migrating an 'old' website into WordPress the does not use 'friendly permalinks'.

Presently the page URL's read like '.../index.php?article=0058280".

How can I retain the legacy URL's for old imported posts *(there are over 50k entries presently indexed by Google)*, but use friendly URL's for all future posts.

Comment: It wouldn't be enough to import old articles with the friendly-url option off and then turn it on only for the next articles? or is there a cron that creates all the url periodically? Sorry about my english..

Comment: Here is my solution. The number "0058280" is the article's index number. A script was required to bring it into the WP GUID column, to get a standard plain URL of "/?p=0058280". Next a rewrite script in the .htaccess file changes the Google indexed URL from "/index.php?article=0058280" to "/?p=0058280". WP then automatically passes on the GUID URL to the new 'Friendly URL'.